# Converting xoops comments to Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, migration

I have to convert a Xoops project into a Wordpress one.
Right now I'm having problems to convert the Xoops comments to Wordpress.
I got to know the table which stores the comments is the table "xoopscomments", but I don't know the meanings of the fields of it and I searched a lot around and found nothing about it.
Just about the class "XoopsComment".

Does anybody know?
Here is the schema of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `xoops_xoopscomments` (
  `com_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `com_pid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_rootid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_modid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_itemid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_icon` varchar(25) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `com_created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_modified` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_uid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_ip` varchar(15) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `com_title` varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `com_text` text collate latin1_general_ci,
  `com_sig` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `com_exparams` varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `dohtml` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `dosmiley` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `doxcode` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `doimage` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `dobr` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`com_id`),
  KEY `com_pid` (`com_pid`),
  KEY `com_itemid` (`com_itemid`),
  KEY `com_uid` (`com_uid`),
  KEY `com_title` (`com_title`(40))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=19443 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need these fields:

1. com_itemid (Post ID)
2. com_uid ( User ID )
3. com_text ( Comment Text )
4. com_status ( Status )
5. com_created ( Date )

Then get User info ( `uname`, `email` ) by `com_uid` from the `users` table than Insert all data into Wordpress `wp_comments` table:

- comment_post_ID
- comment_author (username)
- comment_author_email
- comment_content
- comment_approved
- comment_date

Comment: As far as I remember I used some query like you are saying. ;)